# Scikit learn NMF how to adjust sparseness of resulting factorization?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

Nonnegative matrix  factorization is lauded for generating sparse basis sets. However, when I run `sklearn.decomposition.NMF` the factors are not sparse. Older versions of NMF had a 'degree of sparseness' parameter `beta`.  Newer versions do not, but I want my basis matrix `W` to actually be sparse. What can I do? (Code to reproduce problem is below).

I have toyed around with increasing various regularization parameters (e.g., `alpha`), but am not getting anything very sparse (like in the paper by [Lee and Seung (1999)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10548103/) when I apply it to the [Olivetti faces dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/real_world.html#the-olivetti-faces-dataset). They still basically end up looking like eigenfaces.

My CNM output (not very sparse):

[image: not very sparse]

Lee and Seung CNM paper output basis columns (looks sparse to me):

[image: pretty, pretty sparse]

Code to reproduce my problem:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF

faces, _ = fetch_olivetti_faces(return_X_y=True)    

# run nmf on the faces data set
num_nmf_components = 50
estimator = NMF(num_nmf_components, 
                init='nndsvd',
                tol=5e-3,
                max_iter=1000,
                alpha_W=0.01,
                l1_ratio=0)
H = estimator.fit_transform(faces)
W = estimator.components_

# plot the basis faces
n_row, n_col = 6, 4 # how many faces to plot
image_shape = (64, 64)
n_samples, n_features = faces.shape
plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))
for face_id, face in enumerate(W[:n_row*n_col]):
  plt.subplot(n_row, n_col, face_id+1)
  plt.imshow(face.reshape(image_shape), cmap='gray')
  plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Is there some combinations of parameters with `sklearn.decomposition.NMF()` that lets you dial in sparseness? I have played with different combinations of `alpha_W` and `l1_ratio` and even tweaked the number of components. I still end up with eigen-face looking things.

Comment: Set l1_ratio and alpha_W both > 0. The larger they are the sparser W and H will be.

Comment: Yes, have tried the results are not pretty. I would love to see an answer with values that worked, and for bonus points an explanation, and triple bonus why was the sparsity parameter taken away.

Comment: If you want "values that work" for regularization you're going to need a principled way to set hyperparameters. I recommend crossvalidation. The other sparsity hyperparameters were deprecated when the solver was changed to coordinate descent. You would have needed a principled way to set those too.

Comment: Cross validation would let you look at robustness/variance of a particular parameter set but isn't really for setting params. Grid search will let you search param space, though it's not exactly principled. 

The problem here is that this algorithm is touted as one that finds a sparse representation, but it often doesn't (e.g., https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3312776/). I've searched param space with this data and not found a sparse representation, that's the point of my question. I will try to clarify it in original question when I have time, and will add a grid-search....

Comment: Continued...My question was partly "Someone must have already done this -- this is a common face data set, a common algorithm. What are the params that will reproduce what we ssee in the standard paper in the field?" I had sort of assumed this was just a common thing people teaching NMF have run into and there is just an off the shelf answer that I am not seeing. But...I think I was wrong because if that was the case someone would have grabbed their reputation points already. :)

Comment: The algorithm you're looking at uses l0 norm (I would not say that this is a common approach), instead of the l1/l2 norm implemented in sklearn, so you'd have to implement it yourself. That said, it shouldn't be too difficult, and I can think of a couple ways that should probably work wrapping the sklearn NMF (but I don't think it's something that would fit in a stackoverflow answer). My intuition is that it doesn't have any real advantages over regularizing by l1 and setting the l1 parameter meet some chosen matrix reconstruction error.

Comment: Yes, that was to point out the issue I don't plan to implement the L0 norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here that we need to disentangle. First, what happened to `sparseness`? Second, how do you generate sparse faces using the sklearn function?

### Where did the sparseness go?

The `sklearn.decomposition.NMF` function went through a major change from versions `0.16` to `0.19`. There are multiple ways to implement nonnetative matrix factorization.

Before `0.16`, NMF used projected gradient descent as described in [Hoyer 2004](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0408058), and included a *sparseness parameter* (which as OP noted let you adjust the sparseness of the resulting W basis).

Because of various limitations outlined in [this extremely thorough issue at sklearn's github repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4811), it was decided to move on to two additional methods:

- Release 0.16: coordinate descent ([PR here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4852) which was in version 0.16)
- Release 0.19: multiplicative update ([PR here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/5295) which was in version 0.19)

This was a pretty major undertaking, and the upshot is we now have a  great deal more freedom in terms of error functions, initialization, and regularization. You can read about that at the issue. The objective function is now:

[image: objective_function]

You can read more details/explanation [at the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html#sklearn.decomposition.NMF), but to note a few things relevant to the question:

- The `solver` param which takes in `mu` for multiplicative update or `cd` for coordinate descent. The older projected gradient descent method (with the sparseness parameter) is deprecated.
- As you can see in the objective function, there are weights for regularizing W and for H (`alpha_W` and `alpha_H` respectively). In theory if you want to reign in W, you should increase `alpha_W`.
- You can regularize using the L1 or L2 norm, and the ratio between the two is set by `l1_ratio`. The larger you make `l1_ratio`, the more you weight the L1 norm over L2 norm. Note: the L1 norm tends to generate more sparse parameter sets, while the L2 norm tends to generate small parameter sets, so in theory if you want sparseness, then set your `l1_ratio` high.

#### How to generate sparse faces?

The examination of the objective function suggests what to do. Crank up `alpha_W` and `l1_ratio`. But also note that the Lee and Seung paper used multiplicative update (`mu`), so if you wanted to reproduce their results, I would recommend setting `solver` to `mu`, setting `alpha_W` high, and `l1_ratio` high, and see what happens.

In the OP's question, they implicitly used the `cd` solver (which is the default), and set  `alpha_W=0.01` and `l1_ratio=0`, which I wouldn't necessarily expect to create a sparse basis set.

But things are actually not that simple. I tried some initial runs of coordinate descent with *high* `l1_ratio` and `alpha_W` and found very low sparseness. So to quantify some of this, I did a grid search, and used a sparseness measure.

Quantifying sparseness is itself a cottage industry (e.g., [see this post, and the paper cited there](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/43250/51564)). I used Hoyer's measure of sparsity, adapted from the one used in the [nimfa package](https://nimfa.biolab.si/):

```
def sparseness_hoyer(x):
    """
    The sparseness of array x is a real number in [0, 1], where sparser array
    has value closer to 1. Sparseness is 1 iff the vector contains a single
    nonzero component and is equal to 0 iff all components of the vector are 
    the same
        
    modified from Hoyer 2004: [sqrt(n)-L1/L2]/[sqrt(n)-1]
    
    adapted from nimfa package: https://nimfa.biolab.si/
    """
    from math import sqrt # faster than numpy sqrt 
    eps = np.finfo(x.dtype).eps if 'int' not in str(x.dtype) else 1e-9
    
    n = x.size

    # measure is meant for nmf: things get weird for negative values
    if np.min(x) < 0:
        x -= np.min(x)
        
    # patch for array of zeros
    if np.allclose(x, np.zeros(x.shape), atol=1e-6):
        return 0.0
    
    L1 = abs(x).sum()
    L2 = sqrt(np.multiply(x, x).sum())
    sparseness_num = sqrt(n) - (L1 + eps) / (L2 + eps)
    sparseness_den = sqrt(n) - 1
    
    return sparseness_num / sparseness_den
```

What this measures actually quantifies is sort of complicated, but roughly a sparse image is one with only a few pixels active, a non-sparse image has lots of pixels active. If we run PCA on the faces example from the OP, we can see the sparseness values is low around 0.04 for the eigenfaces:

[image: sparse eigenfaces]

#### Sparsifying using coordinate descent?

If we run NMF using the params used in the OP (using coordinate descent, with low `W_alpha` and `l1_ratio`, except with 200 components), the sparseness values are again low:

[image: nmf faces original]

If you look at the histogram of sparseness values this is verified:

[image: sparseness pca vs nmf original]

Different, but not super impressive, compared with PCA.

I next did a grid search through `W_alpha` and `l1_ratio` space, varying them between 0 and 1 (at 0.1 step increments). I found that sparsity was not maximized when they were 1. Surprisingly, contrary to theoretical expectations, I found that sparsity was only high when `l1_ratio` was 0 and it dropped of precipitously above 0. And within this slice of parameters, sparsity was maximized when `alpha_W` was 0.9:

[image: cd sparse optimized]

Intuitively, this is a huge improvement. There is still a lot of variation in the distribution of sparseness values, but they are much higher:

[image: histogram optmized cd nmf]

However, maybe in order to replicate the Lee and Seung results, and better control sparseness, we should be using multiplicative update (which is what they used). Let's try that next.

#### Sparsifying using multiplicative update

For the next attempt, I used multiplicative update, and this behaved much more as expected, with sparse, parts-based representations emerging:

[image: mu faces]

You can see the drastic difference, and this is reflected in the histogram of sparseness values:

[image: sparseness mu]

Note the code to generate this is below.

One final interesting thing to note: the sparseness values with this method seem to increase with the component number. I plotted sparseness as a function of component, and this is (roughly) born out, and was born out consistently over all my runs of the algorithm:

[image: sparseness vs component num]

I have not seen this discussed elsewhere, so thought I'd mention it.

#### Code to generate sparse representation of faces using the `mu` NMF algorithm:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF

faces, _ = fetch_olivetti_faces(return_X_y=True) 

num_nmf_components = 200
alph_W = 0.9  # cd: .9, mu: .9
L1_ratio = 0.9 # cd: 0, L1_ratio: 0.9

try:
    del estimator
except:
    print("first run")
    
estimator = NMF(num_nmf_components, 
                init='nndsvdar', # nndsvd
                solver='mu', 
                max_iter=50,
                alpha_W=alph_W,
                alpha_H=0, zeros
                l1_ratio=L1_ratio,
                shuffle=True)

H = estimator.fit_transform(faces)
W = estimator.components_

# plot the basis faces
n_row, n_col = 5, 7 # how many faces to plot
image_shape = (64, 64)
n_samples, n_features = faces.shape
plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))
for face_id, face in enumerate(W[:n_row*n_col]):
    plt.subplot(n_row, n_col, face_id+1)
    face_sparseness = sparseness_hoyer(face)
    plt.imshow(face.reshape(image_shape), cmap='gray')
    plt.title(f"{face_sparseness: 0.2f}")
    plt.axis('off')
plt.suptitle('NMF', fontsize=16, y=1)
plt.tight_layout()
```